# i can't execute bootstrap files on localhost xampp

Tags: javascript, html, github, xampp, localhost

i have downloaded this project from github: https://github.com/DrA1ex/fourier

I am using XAMPP, localhost.

i am new to github, so i wish for detailed help on this one.

i have cloned the project into my htdocs folder, when i try to connect to it won't work.

When i click on the index.html file located in the src folder, it leads to a blank page.

The project is using bootstrap and i don't know how to make it work.

Is there any more info needed, to solve this, please let me know.

Best regards

Comment: I don't think that cloning is the only thing that you need to do. Maybe you need to build this app?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use XAMPP for this project since it is using javascript and Node to run everything.

What you need to do is have node installed on your computer. Go to [Nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/) and download the recommended LTS version. This will also install npm (Node Package Manager)

After the installation, go to your project folder, where the file **package.json** is located, open a terminal (CMD - Command Line) and run:

```
npm install
```

This will download all the dependencies that are needed for this project to work.

When it is done, you just need to open a terminal again on the same directory and run:

```
npm start
```

Your project will run on localhost (a link will probably appear on your terminal). For me, the project run on http://localhost:4200/ but for you it might be different.

Hope this helps